# Find several MAX values in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, max, having

I have a problem with one tricky query.

So, I have a table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE correlations
(
    key1 integer not null,
    key2 integer not null,
)
```

From there I need to select list of `key1`'s which correspond to the highest number of key2. That is, it should return `key1 = 1` and `key2 = 2` because both are there 2 times, meaning that among all these "2" is the highest number.
The problem here that it must return many `key1` fields. If it was just one it would have been a pieace of cake.

So, what I have now:

```
SELECT key1, count(key2) AS ccc
FROM correlations
GROUP BY key1
HAVING ccc = MAX(ccc)
```

Naturally it does not work... because that's not how you use `MAX`.

How can I modify this query to make it work as intended?

This is for SQLite, not MySQL or other db, so I can't use any fancy tricks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have several subqueries to satisfy your needs.

```
SELECT  a.*     -- gets all rows that category belong to greatest count
FROM    correlations a
WHERE   category IN
        (
            SELECT  category     -- gets all category which count is equal
            FROM    correlations -- to the greatest counts
            GROUP   BY category
            HAVING  COUNT(*) =
                    (
                        SELECT  DISTINCT COUNT(*) totalCOunt -- gets the maximum
                        FROM    correlations                 -- count
                        GROUP   BY category
                        ORDER   BY totalCOunt Desc
                        LIMIT   1
                    )
        )
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/21afa/6)

OUTPUT

```
╔════╦══════════╗
║ id ║ category ║
╠════╬══════════╣
║  1 ║        1 ║
║  2 ║        1 ║
║  3 ║        2 ║
║  4 ║        2 ║
╚════╩══════════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by joining back to the original data.  Here is a method using `in`:

```
SELECT id, count(category) AS cat
FROM correlations c
GROUP BY id
where c.cnt = (select max(cnt)
               from (select c2.id, count(c2.category) as cnt
                     from correlations c2
                     group by c2.id
                    ) t
              )
```

Comment: Sorry, I changed my question to give arbitrary field names for better understanding of actual question after you already answered.